# Android floating windows ( separated activities for multi-tasking )

Tags: android, multitasking, floating

How to create floating activities for Android? It seems not impossible as I found a [workable sample][1] in the store. It seems that even Android 2.1+ already supports this. Any idea how to start?

Comment: Check out this thread on XDA, I guess it's the easiest approach to this kind of apps http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531